# iOS and Android Emulators for Visual Studio Code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I've installed the React Native Tools extension for Visual Studio Code. I thought this included the iOS and Android emulators for me to test my React Native app but when I run

`React Native: run ios`

I get an error that reads

> Running the contributed command:'reactNative.runIos' failed.

Do I install these emulators separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS Simulator is distributed with Xcode. You can download it on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) (accessible with a free AppleID) or from the Mac App Store.

It is only available on macOS, with Xcode 8+ requiring macOS El Capitan or newer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot build for iOS in that case. You might be interested in [Expo](https://expo.io/), which enables you to load your code onto a physical iPhone/iPad without a Mac. However, with Expo your app must be pure Javascript and you cannot use native code or any libraries with native dependencies.

Comment: Actually he can run iOS simulator (running on a remote Mac) from within Visual Studio on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get IOS Simulator in VS Code, install Xcode and open it, then go to Preference > Location and there you will see Command Line Tool. Just click the drop-down button and save something like Xcode 11(Version) and save it. Also, I recommend getting IOS and Andriod Simulator in VS Code.